# Flagging in SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am looking to flag the users based on a condition in sql. how can this be done in sql?

For example: in the below table, if any ID's date2 >= date1 then it should flag as "A" else "B". However if date2 < date1 then even for cases date2 >= date1 should be flagged as "B". How can this be achieved in SQL?

Result is expected as shown in Result Column

```
ID  Date1           Date2            Result
100 15 March 2018   15 April 2018    B 
100 15 March 2018   15 January 2018  B
101 15 March 2018   15 April 2018    B
101 15 March 2018   20 June 2018     B
101 15 March 2018   17 January 2018  B
101 15 March 2018   14 July 2018     B
105 15 March 2018   25 May 2018      A
```

Comment: what did you try and what were the problems faced?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried. And tell us what DB you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a simple `case` expression - which is the SQL equivalent of an `if...then...else` block - combined with a windowed function to find the `min` `Date1` and `Date2` values for the 'whole ID' comparison.

In your case this looks like:

```
declare @t table(ID int, Date1 date, Date2 date);
insert into @t values
 (100, '20180501',   '20180415')
,(100, '20180501',   '20180115')
,(101, '20180501',   '20180415')
,(101, '20180501',   '20180620')
,(101, '20180501',   '20180117')
,(101, '20180501',   '20180714')
,(105, '20180501',   '20180525');

select ID
      ,Date1
      ,Date2
      ,case when min(Date2) over (partition by ID) < min(Date1) over (partition by ID)
              then 'B'
              else case when Date2 >= Date1
                          then 'A'
                          else 'B'
                          end
              end as Result
from @t;
```

Output:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| ID  |        Date1        |        Date2        | Result |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 100 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 15.04.2018 00:00:00 | B      |
| 100 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 15.01.2018 00:00:00 | B      |
| 101 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 15.04.2018 00:00:00 | B      |
| 101 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 20.06.2018 00:00:00 | B      |
| 101 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 17.01.2018 00:00:00 | B      |
| 101 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 14.07.2018 00:00:00 | B      |
| 105 | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 | 25.05.2018 00:00:00 | A      |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Awesome, this is working as required. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Hi Dave, another clarification needed on the above. In any of the case if ID has transaction only on 01.05.2018 even then it should be flagged as "A". Your current logic is showing these cases as "B" at the moment.

Comment: @Duser  Have you tried adding this logic in yourself?  Remember that SO isn't a code writing service.